# How to redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com on cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a bucket on s3. Cloudfront is set to serve the content of the bucket as its origin.

Cloudfront has 2 CNAME : `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`. They both work but I would like to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com to avoid duplicate content for google seo.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the following guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Section: To redirect requests from www.example.com to example.com